# Convert signature to vector on OSX?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I need to convert this signature into a single path

[image: Raster Signature]

This might not be the correct term for what I'm trying to achieve, but basically I want to transform the inside of the shape into a "stroke" without the outside paths, so that I can work with it in CSS.

I've stumbled upon this [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/how-can-i-convert-a-jpg-signature-into-strokes) that talks about something called centerline tracing which seems to be exactly what I need, the problem is that the software is not available for OSX.

Does anyone know any other way I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried [Delineate](http://delineate.sourceforge.net/download.html)? It's based on AutoTrace, in fact they link to it on their home page... Also are you comfortable using the cmd line?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. Not really comfortable with cmd, can handle the basics mostly @SkipJack

Comment: UPDATE: Delineate is no longer supported on OSX. Any other suggestions @SkipJack

Comment: hey sorry about that... I would recommend trying Illustrator's Image Trace (or Live Trace) tools. Just played around with it a bit and it seems like exactly what you're looking for. There's an option for strokes instead of fills. From what I've read none of these tools are perfect but here's a detailed [tutorial](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeillustrator/2013/07/image-trace-in-illustrator-a-tutorial-and-guide.html) on it and I'll add an answer if I have time to go through it more thoroughly.

Comment: I played with it for a while, but the results were pretty bad. I'll try it again, if you manage to have a go let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I added an answer below. It's not perfect but hopefully will give you some options. If you elaborate on what exactly you're attempting to do with CSS I can try to help more...

Comment: @SkipJack wow, your signature turned out great. I've tried with mine and it didn't turn out that great though. I'm trying to animate the signature using the stroke-dash + dash-offset trick, to make it appear like its drawing itself [Like so](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)

Comment: yeah I figured you might be trying to do that... The fills/outline one came out really well but it doesn't help you much with the stroke animation. As you probably saw in the comments I need to try some other settings/modes but to be honest your best bet might be to just use the path tool and just trace the signature by hand. Even the other centerline conversions I did were less than optimal. I'll update the answer when I have some free time.

Comment: Thanks once again! I'll try, and update with the results in case I find any other solution

Answer (score 1):

So far I've found two options but I'm sure there's more. Here's the image I used to test both:

[image: Lara Croft Signature]

### Raster to Vector Converter

[This tool](http://online.rapidresizer.com/tracer.php) made by RapidResizer, who offer other free tools as well, does a pretty good job. They have options for centerline tracing and outline tracing. Here's the [outline result](http://rrtrace.herokuapp.com/trace.php?s3=4799808ebce23719fcda2539a2cea07e&type=outline&cornerThreshold=1&output=pdf) and [centerline result](http://rrtrace.herokuapp.com/trace.php?s3=4799808ebce23719fcda2539a2cea07e&type=centerline&cornerThreshold=1&output=pdf). I also found a pretty good [tutorial](http://cleversomeday.com/rrcenterline/) for the tool (although it's pretty easy to figure out).

You can change the `&output=pdf` part of the url to `&output=svg` to get an SVG instead (output seems to be missing from the initial options).

---

### Illustrator

As mentioned above, Adobe Illustrator CC (and older versions) offers a feature called [Image Trace](http://blogs.adobe.com/adobeillustrator/2013/07/image-trace-in-illustrator-a-tutorial-and-guide.html) which provides a variety of options and modes. To create an outline trace you simply open the image in Illustrator and look for the <kbd>Image Trace</kbd> button in the top toolbar. Hitting it will use the default mode to trace the image, *however* it's better to choose a mode based on the image you're vectorizing (using the arrow on the right). In this case I used `Black and White Logo` and got this result:

[image: Image Trace Fills]

I got centerline tracing to work by going to the `Window` dropdown in the top menu and opening the `Image Trace` window. I unchecked `fills` and checked `strokes` instead and then bumped up the `stroke` up to 100px. This worked OK on a few other test images but the best I could get with the signature was this:

[image: Image Trace Strokes]

As you can see this did use centerline tracing but yielded a pretty weak result. However it should be noted that I'm no expert and there's probably ways to optimize the image and change the settings to get a better result.

**Update:** See @joojaa's comments below. I'll update this section as soon as I have more time.

---

### Conclusion

As you can see from the outputs the centerline tracing is a lot harder to get right. Even with a black and white image, like the one I tried, the results were less than ideal (to be fair though I probably could have optimized it more). On the bright side the **outline** and **fill** tracing options work pretty well.

> This might not be the correct term for what I'm trying to achieve, but basically I want to transform the inside of the shape into a "stroke" without the outside paths, so that I can work with it in CSS.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but, assuming you're trying to embed an SVG element with the converted vector, you can style it's contents with CSS or manipulate the elements with JavaScript whether it is an outline traced vector or centerline traced vector. So because the results are much better I would recommend using *outline* or *fills* method but if you have the time definitely read through the tutorials I linked to above and the related question below.

---

### Related Questions

[Converting Drawing to Vector in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26131/converting-drawing-to-vector-in-illustrator)

Comment: Are you sure your doing it right? [This](http://i.imgur.com/B0ThzSq.png) is what i get and i dindt optimize much anything .

Comment: @joojaa not sure at all. You are talking about illustrator centerline tracing right?

Comment: @joojaa if so pls share your steps or feel free to edit that section of the answer.

Comment: Yes but the tracing tool in illustrator CC is much worse then the old one. Best not to use too wide max stroke widths

Comment: @joojaa So you got that using CS5 or CS6? If I don't bump that stroke width up in CC, it barely picks up anything...

Comment: Yes, but the thing is if you bump it too high its starts to combine lines so it has to be right size not too wide and not too thin. It helps if you down res your image first as it makes tracing faster and you get faster previews.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41219/discussion-between-skip-jack-and-joojaa).